# How to expose outside an ip address in vmware

Tags: networking, kubernetes, centos, ip

I have an ip address which is assigned by metallb to a service in k8s. I use vmware with vsphere.

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.99.151.233    10.133.2.21   80:31981/TCP,443:30293/TCP   6d23h
```

The external ip can not be accessed by outside. What can I do in order make it accessible from outside?
I don't want to set the same ip as the vm's ip as external ip.

Comment: What do you mean by "from outside" ? From the public Internet ? Since your particular IP `10.133.2.21` is a private one it cannot be accessed from outside. Do you have a public IP address configured on that VM ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you go for a public IP or you use some **HAProxy** or similar as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#using-a-self-provisioned-edge)

> This is particularly suitable for private Kubernetes clusters where none of the nodes has a public IP address.